# How can i export result from view drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

How can I export my view result in a csv,  xls or xml file?

My view successfully giving the results. Now I want to export the result of my view.

Is there any way to do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check below module for **Views data export** in drupal ?
This module is designed to provide a way to export large amounts of data from view in Drupal.

- http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export
- http://drupal.org/project/views_bonus

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module.

From the project page:

> This module augments Views by allowing bulk operations to be executed
>   on the displayed rows. It does so by showing a checkbox in front of
>   each node, and adding a select box containing operations that can be
>   applied. Drupal Core or Rules actions can be used.

There are also a *ton* of links to examples there as well.

Comment: i tried this one. I got the checkbox and Dropdown box , but dropdown was empty for me. In the settings section "The selected operations" seems empty

Comment: It seems VBO needs extra code for exports. E.g. see here: http://www.xenyomedia.com/drupal/pastebin/121/vbo-export-csv